# How to unmount dev/sda1 manually?

Tags: windows

Please help me how to delete partition and how to unmount "dev/sda1" on gparted? i can't install windows 7 and every time i try, it says i need to unmount manually. Please teach me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

To unmount use the below command

```
umount /dev/sda1
```

If you are not an root user, and having difficulties, you can sudo to root and then unmount the drive

Comment: i also tried that one but still locked and can unmounted. do you have other one to solve my problem?

Comment: when i tried that. this is the one i got. device is busy. (in some cases useful info about processes that use the device is found by lsof(08) or fuser(1)) so what am i going to do next?